# jquery - Select id dynamically with dynamic data in array

Tags: php, jquery

i have a html select tag like given below and using jquery for selecting id dynamically as given in below code  `var trainingnameCtrlVal = $("#x" + i + "_TRAINING_NAME[]").val();`.i am getting an error if i use `var trainingnameCtrlVal = $("#x" + i + "_TRAINING_NAME").val();` this will not shows any result.

```
<select data-table="assessment_training" 
data-field="x_TRAINING_NAME"
data-value-separator=", " id="x3_TRAINING_NAME[]" 
name="x3_TRAINING_NAME[]" multiple="multiple" 
class="form-control">
<option value="62">Induction Training</option></select>
```

I used below code to execute but i am getting error

```
var z = $('select[data-field="x_TRAINING_CATEGORY"]').length-1;
    var training_name = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= z; i++) {  
        var trainingnameCtrlVal = $("#x" + i + "_TRAINING_NAME[]").val();
        training_name.push(trainingnameCtrlVal);
        alert(trainingnameCtrlVal);
    }

 Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #x1_TRAINING_NAME[]
```

Comment: the problem is the `[]` in `x3_TRAINING_NAME[]`

Comment: Use `$("#x" + i + "_TRAINING_NAME\\[\\]")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use like this

```
$("[id='"+'x'+i+'_TRAINING_NAME[]'+"']")
```

or

```
var a = 'x'+i+'_TRAINING_NAME[]'
$("[id='"+a+"']")
```

**Check snippet below**

```js
$("select").on("click", function(){
i = 3
var a = 'x'+i+'_TRAINING_NAME[]'
alert($("[id='"+a+"']").val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select data-table="assessment_training" 
data-field="x_TRAINING_NAME"
data-value-separator=", " id="x3_TRAINING_NAME[]" 
name="x3_TRAINING_NAME[]" multiple="multiple" 
class="form-control">
<option value="62">Induction Training</option></select>
```

Comment: just click on select box item

Comment: @AnilKumarReddy  click on 'Induction Training' of select .U will see alert with its value